# Изменение размера картинок на разных устройствах

Tags: html, css

Как сделать изменение размера картинок на разных устройствах на адаптивном сайте?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите в сторону CSS [[[@media](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal)

Вот тоже недавно баловался

```
<style>

#page{
width:900px;

border:1px solid red;
font-size:20px;

}

@media screen and (max-width:999px){

    #page{
        width:90%;
        font-size:12px;
    }
}

.text2{
width:50%;
border:1px green dashed;
}

@media screen and (max-width:500px){

    #page{
        width:90%;
        font-size:8px;      
        background:green;
    }
}
</style>
<div id="page">
    <div class="text1">sd </div>
    <div class="text2">sf swrew</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, я тоже с этим делаю, но мне надо, чтобы изображения на сайте подстраивались под мобильные устройства. Сжимались(становились меньше)

Comment: А что мешает добавлять подобные свойства не только к div но и к img
Для моего примера например дописать


#page img{
     width:90%;
}

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось!

Answer (score 1):

Прикрепите к нему класс и в разных блоках `media queries` задавайте разную ширину и высоту картинки.

Другой вариант - иметь несколько картинок и выводить их, скажем, через `background: url(img.png);` и в зависимости от размеров окна, менять эту строчку.